# PHP Array Rename Dynamic Array Keys

Tags: php, arrays

I am needing to rename dynamic array keys, and create a new array.
Here is the array as given:

```
array(21)
{
    ["0161"] =>
    array(5)
    {
        ["L_NAME0161"] =>
        string(13) "john%20Hewett"
        ["L_TRANSACTIONID0161"] =>
        string(17) "50350073XN1446019"
        ["L_AMT0161"] =>
        string(6) "8%2e50"
        ["L_FEEAMT0161"] =>
        string(9) "%2d0%2e55"
        ["L_NETAMT0161"] =>
        string(6) "7%2e95"
    }
    ["08591"] =>
    array(5)
    {
        ["L_NAME08591"] =>
        string(18) "Norbert%20Bendixen"
        ["L_TRANSACTIONID08591"] =>
        string(17) "1WN98871MS4263823"
        ["L_AMT08591"] =>
        string(6) "8%2e50"
        ["L_FEEAMT08591"] =>
        string(9) "%2d0%2e55"
        ["L_NETAMT08591"] =>
        string(6) "7%2e95"
    }
}
```

Here is the code I am using which is not working for me:

```
foreach ($reb AS $newrebarray)
{
    foreach ($newrebarray as $ke => $val)
    {

        if (preg_match("/L_NETAMT/i", $ke))
        {
            $newarrayreb1 = array('Net' => $val);
        }
        if (preg_match("/L_TRANSACTIONID/i", $ke))
        {
            $newarrayreb1 = array('TransactID' => $val);
        }
        if (preg_match("/L_NAME/i", $ke))
        {
            $newarrayreb1 = array('Name' => $val);
        }
    }
}
```

notice that the array keys are dynamic, I want to create a new array with static keys, and the associated values. When I run the code, I get five different arrays.

Comment: so basically you just want to strip the numbers off those keys, leaving only the initial text-only portion, and build a new array with those stripped keys?

Comment: yes Mark, that is what I am wanting to do

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First I would define a function that does replacement based on a captured memory segment of a regular expression:

```
function do_translate($match)
{
    switch ($match[1]) {
        case 'L_NAME':
            return 'Name';

        case 'L_NETAMT':
            return 'Net';

        case 'L_TRANSACTIONID':
            return 'TransactID';
    }
    // in all other cases, return the full match
    return $match[0];
}
```

Then iterate over the blocks, send the array keys through a translation pass and then recombine the new keys with the existing values:

```
foreach ($reb as $id => $data) {
        $new_keys = preg_replace_callback('/^(L_[A-Z]+)' . preg_quote($id) . '$/i', 'do_translate', array_keys($data));
        // create the new array with translated keys
        $reb[$id] = array_combine($new_keys, $data);
}
```

*I noticed that the array keys were a combination of the field and the product id (I guess), so I've used that knowledge to strengthen the regular expression*

Answer (score 1):

Not tested, haven't fully woken up yet, so this'll probably kick your dog and delete all your savegames:

```
$translations = array(
    'L_TRANSACTIONID' => 'Translation',
    'L_NAME' => 'Name',
    'L_NETAMT' => 'Net'
);

foreach($array as $parentkey => $subarray) {
    foreach($subarray as $subkey => $val) {
       if (preg_match('/^(L_.*?)\d*$/', $matches)) {
           $newKey = $translations[$matches[1]];
           $array[$parentkey][$newkey] = $val;
           unset($array[$parentkey][$subkey]);
       }
    }
}
```